# How to read data into array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file

I'm writing a code to solve Ax=b using MATLAB's x=A\B. I believe my problem lies within getting the data from the files into the array. Right now, the solution vector is coming out to be a load of 0's

The matrices I'm using have 10 rows respectively. They are aligned correctly in the text files.

```
% solve a linear system Ax = b by reading A and b from input file
% and then writing x on output file.
clear;
clc;
input_filename = 'my_input.txt';
output_filename = 'my_output.txt';
% read data from file
fileID = fopen('a_matrix.txt', 'r');
formatSpec = '%d %f';
sizeA = [10 Inf];



A = load('b_matrix.txt');

A = A'

file2ID = fopen('b_matrix.txt','r');
formatSpec2 = '%d %f';
sizeB = [10 Inf];

b = load('b_matrix.txt');
fclose(file2ID);

b = b'

% solve the linear system
x = A\b;

% write output data on file 


dlmwrite('my_output.txt',x,'delimiter',',','precision',4);
% print screen
fprintf('Solution vector is: \n');
fprintf('%4.2f \n', x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question but I felt the need to share in case anyone else has similar troubles.

```
% solve a linear system Ax = b by reading A and b from input file
% and then writing x on output file.
clear;
clc;
input_filename = 'my_input.txt';
output_filename = 'my_output.txt';
% read data from file
f = textread('a_matrix.txt', '%f');
vals = reshape(f, 11, []).';
A = vals(:,1:10);
b = vals(:,11);

% solve the linear system
x = A\b;

% write output data on file 

dlmwrite('my_output.txt',x,'delimiter',',','precision',4);
% print screen
fprintf('Solution vector is: \n');
fprintf('%4.2f \n', x);
```

I ended up combining the 'a' and 'b' matrix into a single text file for simplicity. Now, MATLAB reads data in by columns, so it is necessary to use 'reshape' in order to fit the data within the array correctly. Then, I filtered out the information from the single matrix by columns, using the 'vals' function as seen in my code. The 'A' matrix is essentially all numbers in columns 1 through 10, while the 'B' matrix is the 11th (and final) column.

Using MATLAB's x=A\b function, I was able to solve the linear system of equations.